# Can I include another source in the default .env file?

Tags: docker-compose

Is it possible with `docker-compose` to mimic following?

the `.env` file:

```
...
if [ -f "another.env" ]; then
  . ./another.env
fi
....
```

I am getting no errors, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with `env_file` section:

```
version '3.6'
  your-service:
    env_file: ./another.env
```

For more information, have a look to [docker-compose environment conf doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)